Exclude projects in nested folders while using dotnet build of solution file
Folder strucure of our project is below. While building the solution, we need to exclude some projects present. Please let me know if there is a way to exclude some projects while building a solution using dotnet build.
Main Folder
  --ProjA Folder
     --A Folder
       --A.csproj
      --Aa Folder
        -Aa.csproj
     -- B Folder
      --B.csproj
      |
      |
  continues

When we build solution we need to exclude ProjA\A folder projects.
I cant use target property to specify the projects as we have more projects to build. Please let me know if we have option to exclude directory with nested folder proj files from building.
we tried this option and its giving me an error:
 dotnet build Emp.sln  /p:Configuration=Release -p excludeProjects= "C:\Main\ProjA\A\A.csproj" -o C:\Main\Output
Syntax error


The syntax of the command is incorrect.
MSBuild version 17.6.3+07e294721 for .NET
MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.

Please let me know if there is any property that excludes certain projects from build.

@pfx yes.I am referring to dotnet build Emp.sln. Please let me know how can we exclude projects

corrected. Is there a option to exclude or select few projects for build

When Emp.sln is built, only the projects in the Emp.sln solution will be built. There is no "property" that will exclude projects from the build. You can create different .sln files and/or you can create solution filter files (.slnf).
